# Separate Excel user form labels for different users

Tags: vba, excel, user-controls, userform

I have data in a worksheet which have been generated as the user registered to his chosen type of access (as student or as professor). I have a two user forms (frmStudent and frmProfessor). My question is, how to change the userform's captions (name, course/department, gender) as the user logs in.

Example: As user123 logs in, the frmStudent shows and their corresponding name, course and gender listed in the worksheet is what is shown in the labels of their user form. (frmStudent.lblname.caption would be changed to "Bogart MAgnifico" and so does with course and gender.) or if user456 logs in the frmProfessor shows and does the same with the labels.

Also, during their registration, I had them choose which type of access they would want using two option buttons. I have tried using a loop (one which I used as the frmLogin, checks if username and password are correct), but I can't seem to make it work.

Showing the code might help.
Please consider my question as I am new to VBA.

Comment: Please show us the code you have so far

Answer (score 0):

In my dummy workbook I have created these things:

1. In the "Sheet1": row 1 - login names for 2 users; other 2 rows -
   their names & surnames.

   [image]
2. The button is associated with this sub:

```
Sub Excel_login()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

The button is used to call UserForm1 to enter the login. If it is correct UserForm2 is shown.

[image] [image]

3. This is the code under "OK" button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Select Case Me.TextBox1.Text
        Case ws.Range("A1").Value 'userABC
            UserForm2.Caption = ws.Range("A1").Value
            UserForm2.Label2.Caption = ws.Range("A2").Value
            UserForm2.Label3.Caption = ws.Range("A3").Value
            Me.Hide
            UserForm2.Show
        Case ws.Range("B1").Value 'userDEF
            UserForm2.Caption = ws.Range("B1").Value
            UserForm2.Label2.Caption = ws.Range("B2").Value
            UserForm2.Label3.Caption = ws.Range("B3").Value
            Me.Hide
            UserForm2.Show
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Incorrect username."
            Me.Hide
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

4. If a user logs in successfully he sees one of these 2 forms with different label and userForm captions depending on user:

   [image] [image]

**EDIT**

In order not to create a new `Case` for every new user you can just do this:

```
Dim i as long
For i = 1 To ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    If ws.Cells(1, i).Value = Me.TextBox1.Text Then
        UserForm2.Caption = ws.Cells(1, i).Value
        UserForm2.Label2.Caption = ws.Cells(2, i).Value
        UserForm2.Label3.Caption = ws.Cells(3, i).Value
        Me.Hide
        UserForm2.Show
    Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: sir... if I'd do your suggestion, that would mean I would have to make such conditional statement everytime a user registers... that would be tedious... what I want to happen is, for every user that registers... the code automatically runs as the userform is launched for each newly registered user....

Comment: Don't use my suggestion. Build on it! Your main question was: "My question is, how to change the userform's captions (name, course/department, gender) as the user logs in." So, I showed you how you can have different label and userform captions on the same userform (UserForm2) depending on the user which logged in.